# ClouldCode not returning right results (randomnumber range limited)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

My Parse Javascript cloudcode is not working correctly. Basically all my objects have a corresponding "index/menindex & womenindex" number.

If both genders are selected- all items show up (as they should).

If just male or female is selected- it only shows items up to 122309 (womenindex) or 80811 (menindex). I've tried for weeks but cannot figure this one out.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("standardQuery", function(request, response)  {

var maxIndex = 124940;
var maxWomenIndex = 135354;
var maxMenIndex = 105357;

var arrayOfRandomNumbers = new Array();

var query = new Parse.Query("garmentsAPI");

    if (request.params.gender === "Female") {

        //arrayOfRandoms draws on womenIndex, gender set to female

        for (var k = 0; k < 40; k++) {

            var randomIndex =  Math.floor((Math.random()*maxWomenIndex)+1);

            arrayOfRandomNumbers.push(randomIndex);

                }
        query.containedIn("womenIndex", arrayOfRandomNumbers);
        query.notEqualTo ("viewers", request.params.user);


    }else if (request.params.gender === "Male") {

        for (var k = 0; k < 35; k++) {

            var randomIndex =  Math.floor((Math.random()*maxMenIndex)+1);

            arrayOfRandomNumbers.push(randomIndex);

                }

        query.containedIn("menIndex", arrayOfRandomNumbers);
        query.notEqualTo ("viewers", request.params.user);

        //arrayOfRandoms draws on menIndex, gender set to male

    }else{

        for (var k = 0; k < 35; k++) {

            var randomIndex =  Math.floor((Math.random()*maxIndex)+1);

            arrayOfRandomNumbers.push(randomIndex);

                }

        query.containedIn("index", arrayOfRandomNumbers);
        query.notEqualTo ("viewers", request.params.user);

    };


    if (request.params.gender !== "both") {
    query.equalTo ("gender", request.params.gender);
    };

    query.find({

    success: function(objectsInQuery){

        if (objectsInQuery.length > 15) {

            var arrayOSelectedObjects = new Array();

            for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++) { 

                arrayOSelectedObjects.push(objectsInQuery[j]);

            }

            response.success(arrayOSelectedObjects);

        } else{
                // var existingCount = objectsInQuery.count;
                var missingIndex = 15 - objectsInQuery.length;


                // missingIndex = missingIndex - objectsInQuery.count; 

                var query = new Parse.Query("garmentsAPI");
                if (request.params.gender !== "both") {
                query.equalTo ("gender", request.params.gender);
                };
                query.notEqualTo ("viewers", request.params.user);


                query.limit(missingIndex);
                // query.limit = 9 - objectsInQuery.count;


                query.find({

               success: function(objectsInQuery2){

                if ((objectsInQuery.length + objectsInQuery2.length) === 15) {


                    for (var l = 0; l < missingIndex; l++) { 

                        objectsInQuery.push(objectsInQuery2[l]);

                    }

                    response.success(objectsInQuery);


                } else {



                    //who knows


                    var maxIndex2 = 15000;

                    var arrayOfRandomNumbers2 = new Array();

                    for (var m = 0; m < 15; m++) {

                    var randomIndex =  Math.floor((Math.random()*maxIndex)+1);

                    // var randomIndex =  15;

                    arrayOfRandomNumbers2.push(randomIndex);

                    }


                    var query = new Parse.Query("garmentsAPI");
                    query.containedIn("index", arrayOfRandomNumbers2);
                    if (request.params.gender !== "both") {
                    query.equalTo ("gender", request.params.gender);
                    };
                    // query.notEqualTo ("viewers", request.params.user);


                    query.limit(15);

                    query.find ({


                        success: function (objectsInQuery3){

                            response.success (objectsInQuery3);
                        },

                        error:function() {

                            response.error("there was an error");
                        }


                    }); 


                };



                    },
                error:function() {

            response.error ("didn't work");

                }

            }

                );



        };



            },
        error:function() {

            response.error ("didn't work");

        }

        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, all the curly braces you've posted don't match up. Specifically, I can't find the closing brace for this `if` statement...

`if (objectsInQuery.length > 15) {`

It should be the first character of line 173, according to what you've posted...

as such...

```
                });



        };



            },
        error:function() {

            response.error ("didn't work");

        }

        });

});
```

vs. your post, as follows...

```
                );



        };



            },
        error:function() {

            response.error ("didn't work");

        }

        });

});
```

Comment: Sure- I added the closing brace for that statement.